# Cannot set character_set_database and character_set_server to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set, utf-8

I'm trying to convert my MySQL server and its already existing schemas to the utf8mb4 character set.

Preliminary Notes:

- I'm using Xampp (with MySQL 5.6.24). Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
  `C:\WINDOWS\my.ini` `C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf` `C:\my.ini` `C:\my.cnf` `C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini` `C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf`, and none exists at the moment.
- character-set related variables are as follows before creating any option file:

  ```
  mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
  +--------------------------+-------------------+
  | Variable_name            | Value             |
  +--------------------------+-------------------+
  | character_set_client     | cp850             |
  | character_set_connection | cp850             |
  | character_set_database   | latin1            |
  | character_set_filesystem | binary            |
  | character_set_results    | cp850             |
  | character_set_server     | latin1            |
  | character_set_system     | utf8              |
  | collation_connection     | cp850_general_ci  |
  | collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci |
  | collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci |
  +--------------------------+-------------------+
  ```

Now I convert one schema to utf8mb4 (one `ALTER SCHEMA` and multiple `ALTER TABLE`s), everything works fine. Then I create the following `C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf` file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Next step, I stop mysql with xampp control panel, start it again, and go check the character-set related variables:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | latin1             |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

According to [the guide I follow](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets), `character_set_database` and `character_set_server` should be set to **utf8mb4**, and `collation_database` and `collation_server` to **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**. What am I missing?

I have already tried to move my `my.cnf` option to other paths among those read by MySQL (see above), but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found what caused the problem. If `mysqld` is installed as a service,  it sets the path to the executable to:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

*(if XAMPP is installed in `C:\xampp`, of course)*

When `mysqld` is started with the `--defaults-file` argument, it reads [the specified option file only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-file). And as this path doesn't show up in `mysql --help`'s list of options files, I had no idea of its existence.